# Error running supervisord with gearmand on Ubuntu Natty

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gearman, supervisord

I am using Ubuntu Natty.

I'm trying to use supervisord to deamonize gearmand. I've installed both gearmand and supervisord.

However, whenever I start supervisord I get the following log entries:

```
2012-05-18 12:23:29,219 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2012-05-18 12:23:29,287 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2012-05-18 12:23:29,287 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2012-05-18 12:23:29,293 INFO daemonizing the supervisord process
2012-05-18 12:23:29,294 INFO supervisord started with pid 16596
2012-05-18 12:23:30,302 INFO spawned: 'gearman' with pid 16599
2012-05-18 12:23:30,312 INFO exited: gearman (exit status 127; not expected)
2012-05-18 12:23:31,318 INFO spawned: 'gearman' with pid 16630
2012-05-18 12:23:31,329 INFO exited: gearman (exit status 127; not expected)
2012-05-18 12:23:33,337 INFO spawned: 'gearman' with pid 16631
2012-05-18 12:23:33,346 INFO exited: gearman (exit status 127; not expected)
2012-05-18 12:23:36,355 INFO spawned: 'gearman' with pid 16632
2012-05-18 12:23:36,365 INFO exited: gearman (exit status 127; not expected)
2012-05-18 12:23:37,366 INFO gave up: gearman entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

Below is my program entry for gearmand in supervisord.conf

```
[program:gearman]
command=/usr/sbin/gearmand -u root
numprocs=1
directory=/usr/local/php
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisord.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
stopsignal=KILL
```

When I run the command `/usr/sbin/gearmand -u root` in the command line it works ok.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, would appreciate some assistance.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this problem? If so, please share it. I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Well, got this working. One of the path in my program entry was wrong. status 127 says exactly the same.